# Soma/multiplicação de inputs dinâmicos e total em R$

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Boa Tarde,
Preciso de uma grande ajuda, estou travado em um problema que aparentemente deve ser muito fácil! mais não estou conseguindo evoluir.

Tenho um código com os seguintes campos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu script consta com 5 grupos de inputs aparentes e um botão de adicionar mais inputs(inputs dinâmicos), meu problema está na soma dos inputs.

1 - Preciso efetuar a multiplicação dos inputs "Quantidade" X "Valor Und" e seu resultado aparecer no input "Total". No meu atual código esta multiplicação já está sendo feita, o que preciso é que os inputs "Quantidade" e "Valor Und" aceitem  a "," Ex.( 5,50 ).Pois estou trabalhando com unidades de medida e dinheiro.(Essa função deverá ser valida para todos os campos até mesmo os dinâmicos)

2 - Necessito efetuar a soma de todos com inputs "Vltotal" ( até mesmo os dinâmicos ) + o input "outras" e seu resultado aparece no campo "totalnfe". Que deverá ser em formatação de Dinheiro R$. Ex( 2,50 ou 2.005,50)

Como falei acredito que seja uma coisa tão simples, só que não estou conseguindo..

Desde já agradeço!

```js
<script>
    $(function () {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $(".select2").select2();

    //Date picker
    $('#datae').datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
      todayBtn: 'linked',
      language: 'pt-BR',
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true
    });
    $('#datav').datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
      todayBtn: 'linked',
      language: 'pt-BR',
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true
    }); 
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 5;
    //adiciona nova linha
    $("#add").on("click", function () {
        i++;
        
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod" name="cod[]"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="und" name="und[]"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd' + i + '" name="qnd[]"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund' + i + '" name="vlund[]"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal' + i + '" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()"></td>';
        cols += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger deleteLinha">X</button></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        
        $("#products-table").append(newRow);
    });
    
    //chamada da função para calcular o total de cada linha
    $("#products-table").on("blur keyup", 'input[id^="vlund"], input[id^="qnd"]', function (event) {
        calculateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
    });
    
    //remove linha
    $("#products-table").on("click", "button.deleteLinha", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
 
//função para calcular o total de cada linha   
function calculateRow(row) {
    var vlund = +row.find('input[id^="vlund"]').val();
    var qnd = +row.find('input[id^="qnd"]').val();
    //2 casas decimais
    var total = (vlund * qnd).toFixed(2);
    //substitui ponto por virgula
    total=total.replace(".", ",");
    //a regex abaixo coloca um ponto a esquerda de cada grupo de 3 digitos desde que não seja no inicio do numero
    row.find('input[id^="vltotal"]').val((total).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));     
}

$(".soma").blur(function(){
    calcular();
});

function calcular() {
    var soma = 0;
    $(".soma").each(function(indice, item){
        var valor = parseFloat($(item).val());
        console.log(valor);
        if ( !isNaN( valor ) ) {
            soma += valor;
        }
    });
    $("#totalnfe").val(soma)
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
              <table class="table" id="products-table">             
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Cod.</th>
                    <th>Descrição</th>
                    <th>Und.</th>
                    <th>Quantidade</th>
                    <th>R$: UND</th>
                    <th>R$: TOTAL</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control cod" id="cod" name="cod[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control desc" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control und" id="und" name="und[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd" name="qnd[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund" name="vlund[]" onblur="calcular()"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control cod" id="cod" name="cod[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control desc" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control und" id="und" name="und[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd" name="qnd[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund" name="vlund[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod" name="cod[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="und" name="und[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd" name="qnd[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund" name="vlund[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()"></td>
                  </tr>                           
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod" name="cod[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="und" name="und[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd" name="qnd[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund" name="vlund[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()"></td>
                  </tr>                           
                  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod" name="cod[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="und" name="und[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd" name="qnd[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund" name="vlund[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="row">
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar Linhas +</button></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><label for="totalnfe">Outras Despesas</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="outras" name="outras"></td>
                    <td><label for="totalnfe">Valor Total da Nota</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalnfe" name="totalnfe" readonly></td>
                  </tr>  
                </tfoot>
              </table>
              </html>
```

Comment: essas funções do Date picker estão dando erro, falta biblioteca.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Comentários no próprio codigo**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 //chamada da função para calcular valor total
 $(".table").on("change keyup keydown paste propertychange bind mouseover", function(){
     calcular();
 });

    var i = 5;
    //adiciona nova linha
    $("#add").on("click", function () {
        i++;
        
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod" name="cod[]"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="und" name="und[]"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd' + i + '" name="qnd[]"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund' + i + '" name="vlund[]"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input style="display: none;" type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal' + i + '" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()">';
        cols += '<input type="text" class="form-control somaS" id="vltotalS' + i + '"></td>';
        cols += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger deleteLinha">X</button></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        
        $("#products-table").append(newRow);
        
      $(".soma").each(function() {
          $(this).blur(function(){
              calcular();
          });
      });
     
    });
    
    //chamada da função para calcular o total de cada linha
    $("#products-table").on("blur keyup", 'input[id^="vlund"], input[id^="qnd"]', function (event) {
        calculateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
    });
    
    //remove linha
    $("#products-table").on("click", "button.deleteLinha", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
 
 //função para calcular o total de cada linha   
        function calculateRow(row) {
     var vlund = row.find('input[id^="vlund"]').val();
     //retira separadores de milhar ponto
     vlund = vlund.split(".").join("");
     //substitui separador decimal virgula por ponto
     vlund=vlund.replace(",", ".");
     vlund = +vlund;
     var qnd = +row.find('input[id^="qnd"]').val();
     //total para uso nos calculos
     //2 casas decimais 
     var total = (vlund * qnd).toFixed(2);   
     row.find('input[id^="vltotal"]').val(total); 
     //totalS para uso na apresentação substitui separador decimal ponto por virgula
     totalS=total.replace(".", ",");
     //a regex abaixo coloca um ponto a esquerda de cada grupo de 3 digitos desde que não seja no inicio do numero
     row.find('input[id^="vltotalS"]').val((totalS).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."));  
 
 }

 //função para calcular o total da nota 
 function calcular() {
     var soma = 0;
     $(".soma").each(function(indice, item){
         var valor = parseFloat($(item).val());
         //console.log(valor);
         if ( !isNaN( valor ) ) {
             soma += valor;
         }
     });
    
     //pega o valor das outras despesas e caso haja substitue a virgula por ponto
     var outras = (document.getElementById("outras").value).replace(",", ".");
    
     outras=Number(outras);
        soma=(soma+outras).toFixed(2);
     //substitui separador decimal ponto por virgula
     soma=soma.replace(".", ",");
     //a regex abaixo coloca um ponto a esquerda de cada grupo de 3 digitos desde que não seja no inicio do numero
     $("#totalnfe").val((soma).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."))
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<table class="table" id="products-table">             
<thead>
<tr>
 <th>Cod.</th>
 <th>Descrição</th>
 <th>Und.</th>
 <th>Quantidade</th>
 <th>R$: UND</th>
 <th>R$: TOTAL</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control cod" id="cod" name="cod[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control desc" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control und" id="und" name="und[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd" name="qnd[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund" name="vlund[]" onblur="calcular()"></td>
 <!-- todos os inputs com style="display: none; são para uso nos calculos-->
 <td><input style="display: none;" type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()">
 <input type="text" class="form-control somaS" id="vltotalS"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control cod" id="cod" name="cod[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control desc" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control und" id="und" name="und[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd" name="qnd[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund" name="vlund[]"></td>
 <td><input style="display: none;" type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()">
 <input type="text" class="form-control somaS" id="vltotalS"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod" name="cod[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="und" name="und[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd" name="qnd[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund" name="vlund[]"></td>
 <td><input style="display: none;" type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()">
 <input type="text" class="form-control somaS" id="vltotalS"></td>
</tr>                           
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod" name="cod[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="und" name="und[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd" name="qnd[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund" name="vlund[]"></td>
 <td><input style="display: none;" type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()">
 <input type="text" class="form-control somaS" id="vltotalS"></td>
</tr>                           
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="cod" name="cod[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" name="desc[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="und" name="und[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="qnd" name="qnd[]"></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vlund" name="vlund[]"></td>
 <td><input style="display: none;" type="text" class="form-control soma" id="vltotal" name="vltotal[]" onblur="calcular()">
 <input type="text" class="form-control somaS" id="vltotalS"></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
 <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Adicionar Linhas +</button></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td><label for="totalnfe">Outras Despesas</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="outras" name="outras"></td>
 <td><label for="totalnfe">Valor Total da Nota</label><input type="text" class="total" id="totalnfe" name="totalnfe" readonly></td>
</tr>  
</tfoot>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo que queria, a única observação é que o input "outras"devera soma "+"com a somas dos valores.

Comment: @DanilloBraga fica esperto que não é só trocar o sinal de menos (-) na linha soma=(soma-outras).toFixed(2); Antes disso tem que incluir essa linha outras=Number(outras); Já editei a pergunta para somar outras despesas

Comment: Tem um problema: quando inclui um valor no formato "2.005,50" dá "NaN" no total.

Comment: @Dvdsamm só fazer um replace na hora de pegar esse valor

Comment: Isso que achei complicado. Se eu fizer replace em todos os pontos, não daria certo tb, porque 2.005.50 viraria 200550, porque as casas decimais, nesse caso aí do formulário, pode ser separada tanto por ponto quanto por vírgula: 5,5 é o mesmo que 5.5, nesse caso.

Comment: @Dvdsamm editei a resposta veja se acha mais algo que possamos melhorar

Comment: Melhorou, mas com número acima de 1 milhao dá o "NaN": Ex.: 1.000.000,50... Mas isso não importa. Eu entendi errado a pergunta. Essa formatação ele quer no campo "Valor Total da Nota". Tá certinho seu código.

Comment: @Dvdsamm Nesse caso use  vlund = vlund.split(".").join(""); Resposta editada Esses são detalhes fáceis de se corrigir, fica a vontade do usuario, o melhor seria fazer uma validação nos inputs

Comment: Blz. Mas se o cara digitar 1.000.000.50 dá pau. Era isso que eu tava falando. Se o cara digitar . ou , nas decimais, surtisse o mesmo resultado.

Comment: @Dvdsamm mesmo nesse caso há solução, depende da vontade de validar essa entrada, mas temos que partir do principio que deve haver um certo bom senso na entrada de um valor numérico para efeito de calculos matematicos, nem maquinas de calcular aceitam tantos pontos, só aceitam um ponto

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Verdade. Até porque acho difícil que irão trabalhar com valores muito altos.

Comment: @Dvdsamm hahaha, se for usuario lá de Brasilia teremos que corrigir o código

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Eu sou de Brasília, mas no meu caso acho difícil até de usar números com 3 dígitos rsrs...

Comment: @Dvdsamm me dá o numero da sua conta e SENHA que vou depositar algum pra vc :)

Comment: Cara, só não dou porque senão vc vai querer sacar meus 8 reais que tem lá.

Answer (score 0):

Uma sugestão é usar o id do input para pegar os valores dos inputs, multiplica-los e usar o seguinte código para formatar:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}
```