# Soma e Multiplica input dinâmico

Tags: javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho essa função que multiplica `qnt * vlor = subtotal` em uma tabela dinâmica.

Porém ela só faz o cálculo na primeira linha. Gostaria também de puxar o total da soma so subtotal.

Encontrei [esse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233932/soma-multiplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-inputs-din%C3%A2micos-e-total-em-r) mas queria algo mais simples.

**Soma**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#tbodyCotacao").on("blur keyup", function (event) {
      calcular()
});

function calcular(){
    var valor1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('pqnt').value, 10);
    var valor2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('pvlr').value, 10);
    document.getElementById('ptotal').value = valor1 * valor2;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Não vou conseguir formular uma resposta agora, mas você não vai poder usar IDs em elementos repetidos, IDs são únicos. E você também vai precisar entender como funciona delegação de eventos ([esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333053/6333) tem uma boa explicação), pois seus eventos precisam ser escutados pelos _inputs_ já existentes e pelos _ inputs_ que irão existir.

Comment: Entendi, vou ver outra forma aqui

Comment: Tentei fazer assim :  var vQnt = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[id^="pqnt"]').val();  
        var vVlr = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[id^="pvlr"]').val();  

        const quant = parseInt(vQnt);
        const valor = parseInt(vVlr);
        
        alert(quant +'/'+ valor)
        // document.getElementById('ptotal').value = quant * valor;

Comment: Me retorna (NaN)